# Pycharm using older versions of local modules

Tags: pycharm

Given the following structure in a `pycharm` project:

[image]

I have found a repeatable behavior in which changes to the `shbase` module are not being picked up until/unless I restart `pycharm`.  The changes were minor: removing some logging statements. But the changes did not take effect until quitting/restarting `pycharm`.

Any ideas how to force `pycharm` to respect/reload the local module updates without restarting?

Comment: Seems that by some reason PyCharm does not flush edited file to a disk, does `File - Synchronize` help?

Comment: Changes not being picked up, meaning...? When you run some code that calls `shbase`, the changes aren't reflected? Or is it IDE-specific like goto/back suggestions not updated? Also, rather lame possibility, but did you save (with a ctrl+s)?

Comment: @user2235698  I did try file synchronize before and it did not help

Comment: @Melvin As mentioned in the question the newly added  logging statements are not executed - and that's just one example - generally any changes are not reflected and will effect the runtime and/or debug -  so it's not just syntax and navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `shbase` used in the notebook? If yes do you use IPython [autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html)? Try the latest PyCharm 2019.2 early access preview build [192.4787.5](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) as it comes with a relevant fix https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35428

Comment: a. Yes `shbase` is used - and its updates are not visible .  b.  I am not using _autoreload_ and the issues are not about non-python data files but rather with modules/source code.  c. I'll try out latest preview maybe in a day or two: have urgent work and can live with current behavior for a bit. Glad they are getting some love!